# How can I read a single character from the minibuffer?

Tags: minibuffer, interactive

When part of a `defun`,

```
(interactive "c(C)hoose (A)n (O)ption")
```

will prompt the user for a single character; `RET` is not required.  How can I replicate this reading behavior without the need for `interactive`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than `read-char` I recommend `read-key`.  The difference is that `read-key` obeys all the usual remappings such as `input-decode-map` and `function-key-map`, so it will work properly in a tty.

Comment: Paired with the information in [another answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/4168/2264), this seems to be the most precise answer to the question asked :) [glucas's comment](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4167/how-can-i-read-a-single-character-from-the-minibuffer#comment6486_4171) provides a good function though :) `read-char-choice`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [built-in ways to read single events](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-One-Event.html) such as `read-char` and `read-char-exclusive`, here's an option to read a single character, but also specify which characters are acceptable input:

```
(defun read-char-picky (prompt chars &optional inherit-input-method seconds)
  "Read characters like in `read-char-exclusive', but if input is
not one of CHARS, return nil.  CHARS may be a list of characters,
single-character strings, or a string of characters."
  (let ((chars (mapcar (lambda (x)
                         (if (characterp x) x (string-to-char x)))
                       (append chars nil)))
        (char  (read-char-exclusive prompt inherit-input-method seconds)))
    (when (memq char chars)
      char)))
```

So all of the following will accept either "C", "A", or "O":

```
(read-char-picky "(C)hoose (A)n (O)ption: " "CAO")
(read-char-picky "(C)hoose (A)n (O)ption: " '("C" "A" "O"))
(read-char-picky "(C)hoose (A)n (O)ption: " '(?C ?A ?O))
```

And here's an example way to loop for the correct input into a `response` variable:

```
(let (response)
  (while (null (setq response
                     (read-char-picky "(C)hoose (A)n (O)ption: " "CAO")))
    (message "Please pick one of \"C\", \"A\", or \"O\"!")
    (sit-for .5))
  response)
```

Comment: There is also `read-char-choice` which reads one of a given set of characters.

Comment: @glucas: ah, nuts, you're right.  Looks like I reinvented the wheel.

Answer (score 5):

The question was answered long ago, but this additional answer may provide some assistance to other searchers.

`read-char-choice` allows you to specify a list of choices. The fn will not return until the user selects one of those valid options.

```
(read-char-choice "prompt here (A, B, or C)? " '(?A ?B ?C))
```

In the degenerate case in which the options are simply Y or N (case insenstive), there is [`y-or-n-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Yes_002dor_002dNo-Queries.html).

Both `read-char-choice` and  `y-or-n-p` are rigid, and insist on a valid answer. In the former case, it must one of the options you specify (like A, B or C in my example), and in latter case, it must be  Y or N . If the user presses enter or any other key, the `y-or-n-p` will ask again. The `read-char-choice` will just sit there, silent.  Neither provides a way to just return a default. To get that behavior, I think you've got to build your own interaction with `read-char` or `read-key`.

In my experience, the problem with `read-char` and `read-key` alone, is that while they display the prompt in the minibuffer, the cursor remains in the main editing buffer. This is disorienting to the user, and is also  unlike the behavior of `read-string` .

To avoid THAT, you can let the variable `cursor-in-echo-area` prior to calling `read-key` to display the cursor in the minibuffer.

```
(defun my-y-or-n-with-default (raw-prompt &optional default-yes)
  "displays PROMPT in the minibuffer, prompts for a y or n,
returns t or nil accordingly. If neither Y or N is entered, then
if DEFAULT-YES, returns t, else nil."
  (let* ((options-string (if default-yes "Y or n" "y or N"))
         (prompt (concat raw-prompt "(" options-string ")? "))
         (cursor-in-echo-area t)
         (key (read-key (propertize prompt 'face 'minibuffer-prompt)))
         (isyes (or (eq key ?y) (eq key ?Y)))
         (isno (or (eq key ?n) (eq key ?N))))
    (if (not (or isyes isno))
        default-yes
      isyes)))
```

Answer (score 4):

`call-interactively` is what interprets the `(interactive "cPROMPT")` specification, the `c` option is dispatched to `read-char`.  Therefore, the following should work in a non-interactive context:

```
(read-char "(C)hoose (A)n (O)ption")
```